# SCSS - Background-attachment: fixed; Not working in ionic 7 (angular)

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, sass

So I had a mini-app project that I was working on. The primary purpose was to explore some cool CSS designs. One design used a grid of card components that uses a gradient background with a fixed position. I initially tested this in ionic 4, later, I created a new ionic 7 (angular/tabs) application and copy-pasta my CSS. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
  <ol class="list">
    <li>
      <h3>
        Lorem Ipsum
      </h3>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
        standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>
        Lorem Ipsum
      </h3>
      <p>
        when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make
        a type specimen book.
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>
        Lorem Ipsum
      </h3>
      <p>
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
        remaining essentially unchanged.
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>
        Lorem Ipsum
      </h3>
      <p>
        It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
        Lorem Ipsum passages
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>
        Lorem Ipsum
      </h3>
      <p>
        and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions
        of Lorem Ipsum
      </p>
    </li>
  </ol>
```

CSS:

```
@mixin gradient($angle: to right top){
    background: linear-gradient($angle, #051937, #004d7a, #008793);
}

ol{
    list-style-position: inside;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: map-get($map: $z-index, $key: elm);
    position: relative;
    .red{
        @include gradient(to bottom right)
    }
    &>li{
        @extend .center-col;
        @extend .red;
        color: white;
        box-shadow: $z-depth-1;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 320px;
        height: 190px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-attachment: fixed; // <== This is not working in ionic 7 but did in ionic 4
        transition: all .25s ease;
        h3{
            text-decoration: underline;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0 0 10px 0;
        }
        ul{
            padding: 0;
            li{
                text-decoration: none;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When running in my new ionic 4 tabs project, the gradient was fixed to my viewport when I scrolled, which was a nice effect that I wanted to keep. When I imported to my new ionic 7 project, the background gradient was not fixed to my viewport, and it moved with my scroll like normal elements.

My guess is that it has something to do with a configuration, but I am getting bogged down in the new standalone module system that angular uses. Has anyone else run into this?

Comment: When you use your browsers DevTools to inspect the element that has the `background-attachment` property you expect, it can show you what it overriding the rule you set up.  What do the DevTools show you for this element?

Comment: The property `background-attachment` is not being overwritten.